# How do I Copy the same AMI to multiple regions simultaneously?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am trying to find a way to perform a simultaneously copy of a AMI to all other regions.
I have search near and far but beside seeing on a blog post that it can be done, I haven't found a way using aws cli ... 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions/

Currently I have written a bash script to do so, but I would like to find a better, easier way to do so

I have 8 AMI's that need to be passed to all regions.
using an array-

```
declare -a DEST=('us-east-1' ...2....3)
aws copy-image --source-region $SRC --region ${DESTx[@]} --source-ami-id $ami
```

Do you guys have any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can make a single line bash, specially useful if in future there are new regions:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions 
        --output text |\
cut -f 3 | \
xargs -I {} aws copy-image 
        --source-region $SRC 
        --region {} 
        --source-ami-id $ami
```

basically it goes like this:

- `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text` returns the list of all available regions for ec2, its a 3 columns table ("REGIONS", endpoint, region-name)
- `cut -f 3` takes the 3rd column of the previous table (read as list)
- keep the current region from previous argument (xargs) into {} so you can send it to the region parameter of the copy-image command

Comment: Thank you, you have given me a new way to think about this issue.

Comment: Another powerful feature is the --query option - it's more verbose in this case, but useful to know about: aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].{Name:RegionName}' --output text